# Is there any difference between the Hessian matrix and $D^2f(x,y) $ ??

Tags: derivatives, hessian-matrix

**Exercice :**
Let $f :\mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be  the function , defined by :
$$
f(x,y)= \begin{bmatrix}
x+xy^2 \\ -y+y^2+x^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
How we can compute $D^2f(x_0,y_0)(x,y)$ where $(x_0,y_0)=(0,1)$ ?

I'm confused !! if $D^2f(x_0,y_0)$ is the Hessian matrix  of  $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, so how we can compute it?

Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: Just a minor correction, the second derivative here would not be a matrix, it would be a rank 3 tensor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ! I'm so confused !